# Google sheets combine equal values and only return diferent ones

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So today i have a new problem that i am struggling to resolve, i have a list with (Order number, material, color, size, Amout), what i want to do is, write the order number and get all the values from (material, color, size, Amout), but if the values from (material, color, size) are the same i want to combine them and only show them once and sum the amout, is there a way to do that? i tried to use filter and query but i am not getting there, i am going to place some pictures so i can demonstrante better what i want to do.

Orders list

[image: Orders List]

This is what I'm getting with filter or query

[image: This is what i am getting with filter or query]

This is what I want to get

[image: This is what i want to get]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include text based examples in your questions, such as by sharing an editable example sheet

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=query(A:E,"Select B,C,D,sum(E) where A="&G1&" group by B,C,D label sum(E) ''")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `A2:D` contains the parameters that you need to aggregate on, and `E2:E` contains the quantities you need to aggregate...

the following works

```js
=let(unq,unique(A2:D),
     byrow(array_constrain(unq,rows(unq)-1,columns(unq)),
           lambda(r,reduce(0,E2:E,    
                        lambda(a,c,if(and(arrayformula(eq(offset(c,0,column(A2)-column(c),1,column(c)-column(A2)),
                                                          r))),
                                      a+c,
                                      a))))))
```

You are free to grow the list by adding rows or insert more attributes between column A and D as you need.

**Explanations**

The `let` phrase allows for reuse of `unique(A2:D)`, the unique rows of column A to D *including* blank rows. From your examples, there is no blank rows between data rows. So the only blank rows are at the end and thus `unique(A2:D)` contains 1 trailing blank row. That blank row is inconvenient to work with so we remove it with `array_constrain`. (Scanning blank rows can cause performance issues.)

`byrow` means we will work row by row through the unique rows. ie. unique combination of your Order number, material, color, size. For each unique row, we want to aggregate the Amount column *if* the cells to its left match our unique row. To fulfill this task, you can use `reduce` to do the aggregate and `offset` to read the cells to the left.

The parameters of the `offset` is intended to allow to you expand the number of attributes in your Order List. `offset(c,0,-4,4)` works for your example if you do not expand the number of attributes to compare. But how do we read preceding columns in a generalized way? `c` means current cell. `0` means same row as `c`. The left-most column to read is column A. Thus offsetting by `(column(A2)-column(c))`-many columns. we arrive at column A. It doesn't matter if you later insert more columns between column A and the current column E, the difference will reflect that automatically. For how many preceding columns do we need to read? We need to compare all of the preceding columns to the left of `c`. So the number is `column(c)-column(A2)`.

The rest is comparing those preceding cells as a whole to the row from `unique(A2:D)` that we were scanning with `byrow` earlier. `and(arrayformula(eq(...` works to compare rows. If the whole rows are identical, we add it to the accumulator, if not we pass. And this concludes the use of `reduce`.